# 500 Error invalid request ABP framework Login from Angular

Tags: abp

I am using ABP framework with Angular.
Upon clicking login button I am getting [500] Error! invalid_request the following network request result
[image]
[image]

However upon clicking login button. shows me login page and authorize successfully.
[image]

Comment: remove https from your ajax request, make it http://localhost/.....

Comment: also you are getting a 302 instead of a 200 response code.

Answer (score 3):

This issue generally coused by identity server.if you restor database which use different identity server, you should set the client origns table in database with the appsettings.json in the host project
The tables you should set as in your database

```
identityserverclientcorsorigins
identityserverclientpostlogoutredirecturis
identityserverclientredirecturis
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in setting in Database. Database had wrong value for RedirectUris

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

An update on the database is needed indeed, specifically in this table:identityserverclientredirecturis, but what made the difference to me was adding a / (slash) at the end of my url.  I entered both values

https://test.mysite.com and https://test.mysite.com/

and now it works